# PlacementTarget of Contextmenu is not getting set

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My WPF Application is having a button that opens a Contextmenu upon clicking on it.
I am using MVVM pattern and here is the XAML Code.

In the buttonClick() in Viewmodel, IsOpenMenu will be set to true. But i am unable to get the context menu correctly up.

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Column="1" Name="btnView1" Height="25" Width="75" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}"
ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu IsEnabled="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenMenu}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnView1}" Placement="Bottom" >
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu 1" IsCheckable="True"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

But when i set the 3 properties as shown below in the codebehind, i am getting correct results.

```
private void btnView1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
    (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

I feel somehow the PlacementTarget propery on ContextMenu is not getting set properly. 
Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: try setting some breakpoint in the `btnView1_Click` handler to see if it's actually triggered. The code looks fine to me.

Comment: Check that you are correctly performing notify property change on the property IsOpenMenu , and also in the event handler you are using to verify things, check the context menus data context is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately the xaml you have written does not work as you would expect due to how the visual tree works, context menu is not a part of the visual tree that button is in, so for that reason it does not recognise the name btnView1.

Do you need the context menu to appear in the same place every time? If you leave placement target blank it should be placed at the mouse click if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes, i want the context menu just below the button on button click.

Comment: In that case I would just do your code behind workaround instead, it makes more sense to launch the context menu from the code behind rather than the view model anyway. There are some xaml solutions but they are all a bit obtuse, or another option would be to create a new context menu control that inherits namescope from its parent.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. I am going with doing codebehind to set the three properties.

Comment: No problem. If you found my answer helpful (at least the part about the visual tree) please vote up/mark as answer, thanks.